# How to get all realtionships between two nodes using neomodel without using cypherquery()

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, neomodel

I have a node class defined by -

```
class Person(StructuredNode):
    attr = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    name = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
```

Provided that I have fetched two Person Nodesets using nodes.filter(), Is there a way to fetch all the relations existing between them programmatically using Neomodel libraries without using the cypherquery() ?

Answer (score 0):

Well Thanks for well compiled Neomodel documentation, found this can be achieved using neomodel.match.Traversal